# Want to listen a notification when a connected Bluetooth device leave the range

Tags: ios7, xcode5, core-bluetooth

I want to listen a notification when a connected bluetooth device gets out of range. I want that notification in both cases [either the app is running or the app is in suspended state].

Comment: Can you post what you have tried and then what you get stuck on? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: As I have implemented CBCentralManagerDelegate, The didDisconnectPeripheral delegate method won't get called when I take the device out of range.

Comment: Edit your Q and post specific details there, especially your code

Comment: @zaeem: `didDisconnectPeripheral` is never called? It should be, with a certain timeout I guess, but still, it should be called.

Answer (score 2):

As per Developer Documentation: Core Location Documentation 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges.
Apps can expect a notification as soon as the device moves 500 meters or more from its previous notification. It should not expect notifications more frequently than once every five minutes. If the device is able to retrieve data from the network, the location manager is much more likely to deliver notifications in a timely manner.
For detailed info on how to get location services follow this link

http://mobileoop.com/getting-location-updates-for-ios-7-and-8-when-the-app-is-killedterminatedsuspended